# Which Lucidchart license is required for import data to directly get metadata from database to create ERD?

Tags: erd, lucidchart

Wanted to know which Lucidchart license will help to directly connect to the database to extract metadata to created Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD)?
Becasue right now with free account, it's possible to import only Google Sheets, Excel, CSV or plain text which for now I executed the query in the database and manually extracted the output in CSV and imported it for creating ERD.
The requirement will be that lucidchart can directly connect to the SQL database and extract the metadata rather than executing the query , manually extracting the output and importing in lucidchart for ERD.
Any information on the lucidchart license which can help with the above will be helpful. Because even the lucidchart enterprise plans doesn't show the feature of direct connection to database (https://help.lucid.co/hc/en-us/articles/360056903132-Lucidchart-Plans#integrations)

Tried free account, researched enterprise plan but  doesn't show the feature of direct connection to database (https://help.lucid.co/hc/en-us/articles/360056903132-Lucidchart-Plans#integrations)
The requirement will be that lucidchart can directly connect to the SQL database and extract the metadata rather than executing the query , manually extracting the output and importing in lucidchart for ERD.